# Create jar file from linux terminal from different location

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar

I trying to create file from terminal,

```
jar -cvfm Bard.jar ../Bard/out/production/Bard/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ../Bard/out/production/Bard/*.class
```

But this creates same file destinations in jar archive, and give me this exception

```
adding: Bard/out/production/Bard/Main.class(in = 868) (out= 555)
(deflated 36%)
adding: Bard/out/production/Bard/WordProcessor.class(in = 9725) (out= 
4666)(deflated 52%)
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

How should i properly do that?

Comment: What is your full package name (for `Main`)?

Comment: Bard/src/Main.java

Comment: The first line of `Main.java` is `package Bard.src;`? Are you **certain**?

Comment: I meant, that it's in default package.